# Import Error When Running File

Tags: python

When running a Python file I keep getting the following traceback error in IDLE:

```
    File "D:\jmz study\project1\MINI PROJECT\sandhi-splitter-master\sandhi-splitter-master\sandhisplitter\tests\test_splitter.py", line 3, in <module>
        from sandhisplitter.splitter import Splitter
    ImportError: No module named 'sandhisplitter'
```

These are the files I gave:

[image]

Comment: You would need to provide more information before anyone is able to help you. What libraries are you trying to import? It looks like you either haven't properly imported a library or you have spelled the module wrong.

Comment: likely you are missing a __init__ file for any dependency you are trying to include.

Comment: @ThoseKind, I downloaded the library or package and tried the same command, got the same result: [Github sandhi-splitter package](https://github.com/libindic/sandhi-splitter)

Comment: @downshift Looks like it was just a syntax error based on the documentation you linked. See answer below.

Comment: @ThoseKind, cool thanks for sharing your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got a syntax error given that [**this**](https://github.com/libindic/sandhi-splitter) is the right version of the library you are using.

Try using `from sandhisplitter import Sandhisplitter` instead.

Here is an example straight from the library's ReadMe:

```
>>> from sandhisplitter import Sandhisplitter
>>> s = Sandhisplitter()
>>> s.split('ആദ്യമെത്തി')
(['ആദ്യം', 'എത്തി'], [4])
>>> s.split('വയ്യാതെയായി')
(['വയ്യാതെ', 'ആയി'], [7])
>>> s.split('എന്നെക്കൊണ്ടുവയ്യ')
(['എന്നെക്കൊണ്ടുവയ്യ'], [])
>>> s.split('ഇന്നത്തെക്കാലത്ത്')
(['ഇന്നത്തെക്കാലത്ത്'], [])
>>> s.split('എന്തൊക്കെയോ')
(['എന്ത്', 'ഒക്കെയോ'], [3])

>>> s.join(['ആദ്യം', 'ആയി'])
'ആദ്യമായി'
```

Comment: # Wrapper class
# Most functionalities are in model.

from __future__ import absolute_import, division
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
from sandhisplitter.model import Model


class Splitter:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.M = Model(model=model)

    def splits(self, word):
        return self.M.probable_splits(word)
//This is the code which iam looking to run and it is showing the above error